# Após git reset tem como ver git log anterior ao reset?

Tags: git, log, checkout

Eu estava na seguinte situação, estava fazendo um treinamento e cheguei num ponto que minha pagina não estava carregando corretamente ficando diferente do instrutor, tudo indicava um problema de *CSS* então fiz um `git log` e fui fazendo o `git reset` para voltar aos *commits* anteriores e identificar onde que me perdi.

O problema é que quando fiz um `git log` para voltar novamente ao ultimo *commit*, percebi que não aparecia nenhum *log* dos meus *commits* atuais. Por sorte, rolando a pagina do *Cmder*, encontrei o primeiro `git log` e fiz um `git reset` usando o *hash* mais recente e meu projeto voltou ao ultimo status.

Teria alguma forma de fazer isso sem necessariamente perder os *logs* ou `git reset` é apenas para casos sem volta?

Para esta minha necessidade eu deveria ter usado `git checkout <hash>` anterior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível ver o *log* após o `git reset`, basta usar o comando

```
git reflog
```

O `git` mantém um arquivo de *log* que registram todas as modificações (*commit*) do código, independe de *resetar* ou não uma alteração já existente.

ou então

```
git log -g
```

Esse comando é um atalho para `git log --walk-reflogs` e faz basicamente o mesmo que o comando anterior.

Uma outra opção é abrir o arquivo `.git\logs\refs\heads\<nome-do-branch>`. Neste arquivo consta todos os *logs*

---

<sup>**Referência:**</sup>
<sup>https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog</sup>
<sup>https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log</sup>

Comment: Testei aqui e funcionaram perfeitamente muito obrigado.